# Google Maps v2 tiles are only painted after clicks on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm facing an issue when using Google Maps v2 in Android. I want to have a MapView as part of a layout. I'm able to ge the MapView along with a marker, however the tiles themselves don't load UNLESS I click on the map. For each click I do, an additional tile will be painted (so it takes like 4 or 5 clicks to get the whole map).

I'm using Maps V2 but in this particular case, not in a fragment. As a note, the map works ok in another place in which I'm using a MapFragment.

The following are the important snippets of code:

Snippet of the activity:

```
public class ViewNodeDetailsGame extends MapActivity implements View.OnClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mBundle = savedInstanceState;

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_node_details_game);

        // Maps related
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this);

        // ... the data is fetched asynchronously here. Then, getLocation() is called
    }


    private void getLocation(final LinearLayout llLocation) {

        mMapView = (MapView)llLocation.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mMapView.onCreate(mBundle);
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mMapView != null) {
            mMapView.onResume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mMapView != null) {
            mMapView.onPause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        if (mMapView != null) {
            mMapView.onLowMemory();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (mMapView != null) {
            mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestoy();
        if (mMapView != null) {
               mMapView.onDestroy();
        }
    }
```

Snippet of the layout. This layout is added programmatically:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp" />

    <!-- More stuff below -->
```

I am including my API_KEY in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
   <!-- lots of stuff above this... -->
   <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIza --rest of my key here--"
    />
</application>
```

The following images show the progression of tile painting I get with each click. Any tips are appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't call
mMapView.onResume() in Activity's onResume() callback.

Comment: Yes, actually I am. I just didn't add that in the snippet. I just updated the code.

Comment: Is getLoation() called inside onCreate() or from different callstack?

Comment: An asynctask is started in `onCreate()`, which when finished retrieving the data the `getLocation()` method is called.

Comment: why not calling mapView.onCreate() inside activity's onCreate() callback?

Comment: I'm not doing it at the moment because that portion of the view is added depending on the data that is retrieved in the AsyncTask. I'm loading info about a location (name, lat/lon, etc), and only if the lat/lon values are present do I create the MapView.

Comment: Actually that worked. If you add this as an answer I'll accept it.